# Object property always undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This is the first time I've used JS objects and I'm confused as to why this property is always undefined:

```
function Rotator() {
    this.interval = 300;
    this.image = 0;
    this.images = undefined;
}

Rotator.prototype.Fetch = function(links) {
    console.log("Fetch called");
    this.images = links;
}

Rotator.prototype.Current = function() {
    if (this.images == undefined) {
        console.log("Error, images is undefined");
    }
    return this.images[this.image];
}

r = new Rotator;
$.getJSON("./data.php", function (data) {
    r.Fetch(data.images);
});

console.log(r.Current());
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The JSON returned is working fine, and fetch is marked as called in the console (when logged the data is fine as well). Why is Rotator.images always undefined?

Edit: Some console.log results:

- Logging `data.images` in `$.getJSON` results in correct data.
- Logging `links` in `Fetch` results in correct data.
- Logging `this.images` in `Fetch` results in correct data.
- Logging `this.images` in `Current` results in null.

Comment: How and when do you call `r.Current()` ?

Comment: I call Current straight after $.getJSON - I removed the old Fetch call in Current as that was when I had getJSON inside Fetch.

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you tried calling Current after Fetch inside the callback function? I'm guessing getJSON is async and Fetch have not run yet when you call Current after getJSON.

Comment: @Adrian: That worked! So is there some way I can check getJSON has finished?

Comment: You can't. It's async so use callbacks (like you did with Fetch).

Answer (score 2):

Because getting JSON is asynchronous, that's why the data is only available in the callback function.

```
$.getJSON("./data.php", function (data) { // callback function
    r.Fetch(data.images); // this will run when the data is available
});

console.log(r.Current()); // this will run immediately -> data.images is null
```

Everything that depends on the data should be placed in the callback function!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `undefined` that way. Use `null` instead:

```
this.images = null;
```

and

```
if (this.images == null) {
```

#### Edit:

You also have to avoid using the images property if it's null:

```
Rotator.prototype.Current = function() {
  if (this.images == null) {
    console.log("Error, images is undefined");
    return null;
  }
  return this.images[this.image];
}
```

Comment: You can use `undefined` in that way and it works on all major browsers (even IE6 supports it), the only problem is that in ECMAScript 3, the `undefined` global property doesn't exists, and its value is mutable...

Comment: I took that from a website but I've changed it anyway. I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Ross: The error message that you get is because you are trying to use the property even after that you have determined that it's not yet assigned. See my edit above.

Comment: @CMS: You could use any unused variable as "undefined", as it's not defined, which works until it gets defined...

Answer (score 0):

Will this get me purists on my neck or is it acceptable?

```
Rotator.prototype.Current = function() {
    if (this.images) return this.images[this.image];
    console.log("Error, images is undefined, null, empty or 0");
}
```

Comment: You're not solving the problem.